# How to prevent overwriting records in a shared appointment book?

Tags: database, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.3

I am writing a standard appointment book. The book will have three columns per 15:00 minute intervals and will have multiple clients writing to it simultaneously from different locations.

If two user's, A and B, are making appointments at the same time, how do I prevent user B from overwriting user A's appointment? (That is, once user A has
written an appointment, user B's information will be out of date--he won't know what user A did until he attempts to save the appointment record). If the appointment time which user B is wanting to use has already been assigned, I wish user B to be notified that it is not available and not overwrite user A.

I'm sure this is a basic and common problem, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for any help, suggestions, or references.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Comment: Also, you'll be better off only storing actual appointments, not every 15 min interval

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan +1 for defining the real problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the appointments as for example

id, customer_id, time
1 ,32, 2016-03-10 10:15:00
...

just add a unique index on the time column. Then You will have an error if you try to insert a row with the same time. If you want to allow more than 1 bookings at the same time you could add a time_slot column and include that in the index.

id, customer_id, time, time_slot
1 ,32, 2016-03-10 10:15:00, 1
2 ,15, 2016-03-10 10:15:00, 2

```
create unique index appointments_time_timeslot_idx on appointments (time, time_slot);
```

Comment: @BjornNisson After much thought, I came to the same conclusion. The additional problem in my case, is that the actual save is being performed through an Entity Framework which defaults to optimistic concurrency. Managing between the two is a little bit tricky. :)

Comment: Are you sure you even need locking? If you want to reserve the appointment time preliminary you could solve that by have a "confirmed" column. Then you could insert a row as soon as the user selects a time and update the confirmed flag to true when the user confirms.

Comment: You could then for example have a clean up job to delete old unconfirmed bookings.

Comment: Interesting idea...but I'm not sure that the clean up job would not ultimately come back to the initial problem on the "confirmed" column ??

Comment: Not sure what you think would be the problem. The clean up job could delete the unconfirmed bookings older than 15 minutes or something. When the user clicks confirm, you check that the preliminary booking is still there and notify the user if it isn't.